# if i allocate memory dynamically to a static variable should i free it or will it be freed automatically

Tags: c++, dynamic, static, free

if I allocate memory dynamically to a static variable, should I free it or will it be freed automatically?

```
static int* p;

int f(){p = new int[50];}

destructor::~destructor{delete p;}
```

Comment: "will it be freed automatically?" No.

Comment: There is no such thing as "allocating memory to a variable". `p = new int[50];` does not "allocate memory to `p`".

Comment: If you want it freed as the program terminates or library unloads, but do need dynamic allocation, try using a smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to free it yourself, of course! Why would it automatically deallocate the memory it points to? That's the idea of dynamic allocation, you choose when to get rid of the memory! The pointer itself `p` will be destroyed, but the memory it pointed to will remain intact, unless you `delete p` (i.e. deallocate the memory it points to) first. It doesn't change anything just because `p` is `static`.